# Python - kill hung process started using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, kill, freeze

I've started a subprocess using:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Sometimes the command `cmd` hangs so my Python script also hangs at this point.

I'd like to let this run for a time (10 seconds?) and if I don't get a response, then simply kill the process and continue on with my script.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python 3, `Popen.communicate` has a timeout kwarg:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate(timeout=10)[0]
```

Comment: How convenient. I should have read the documentation more closely.

Answer (score 1):

From [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) `proc.terminate()` is what you 're looking for

Comment: yes, I can do that, but what can't do is wait for 10 seconds and then choose to give up. How do I do that?